# C# правильное сравнение в for()

Tags: c#

Есть два столбика с датами `DateTime`. Их нужно сравнить и покрасить в цвет, если значение выше, ниже и тд.

Для конфигурации в будущем, цветов и значений, создал таблицу

```
  |ID|Days|Color |
  |1 |14  |green |
  |2 | 5  |yellow|
  |3 | 0  |gray  |
  |4 |-1  |red   |
```

конфиругацию загружаю в `List<> configList` чтобы потом получить значения и работать с ним.
Суть такова, если разница между днями, больше 14 (из таблицы), приминить цвет зеленый и так далее, если разница между днями -1 и выше - красный. К сожалению результат такой, что всегда приминяется красный.. не пойму, в чем моя логическая ошибка.

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= configList.Count; i++)
 {
    
    // Declare two dates
    var prevDate = new DateTime(2022, 2, 18); 
    var today = new DateTime(2022, 1, 28);
     
    //get difference of two dates
    var diffOfDates = prevDate - today; //(21)

   if(diffOfDate.Days <= configList[i].Days)
   {
      Color CellColor = ConvertColor<Color>(configList[i].Color); 
      e.Appearance.BackColor = CellColor;
      return;
   }
   if(diffOfDate.Days >= configList[i].Days)
   {
      Color CellColor = ConvertColor<Color>(configList[i].Color); 
      e.Appearance.BackColor = CellColor;
      return;
   }

  }


//Convert String into Color
 public T ConvertColor<T>(string text)
{
    return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T))
              .ConvertFromInvariantString(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем сама задача описанна не очень. Но я думаю проблема в этом:

```
   if(diffOfDate <= configList[i].Days)
   {
      Color CellColor = ConvertColor<Color>(configList[i].Color); 
      e.Appearance.BackColor = CellColor;
      return;
   }
   if(diffOfDate >= configList[i].Days)
   {
      Color CellColor = ConvertColor<Color>(configList[i].Color); 
      e.Appearance.BackColor = CellColor;
      return;
```

В чем смысл этих условий если они выполняют одни и те же действия? Наверное больше сказать будет сложно из за непонятного контекста. Попробуй также просто продебажить весь код, пройти его с дебаггером, узнать каждое значение, обычно так ошибки и решаются

Comment: Больше тянет на комментарий, чем на ответ

Comment: проблема скорее больше с последним значением, если дней больше чем 0 - красный цвет не рисуется. Как пример https://i.imgur.com/R4HcO4b.png

Comment: @Insider извини, в том методе не разбираюсь